# How to start gem ffaker in Debian?

Tags: debian, software-installation, ruby, gem

I install [ffaker](https://github.com/ffaker/ffaker) but cannot find it in my PATH

```
masi@masi:~$ sudo gem install ffaker
Fetching: ffaker-2.6.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed ffaker-2.6.0
Parsing documentation for ffaker-2.6.0
Installing ri documentation for ffaker-2.6.0
Done installing documentation for ffaker after 4 seconds
1 gem installed

masi@masi:~$ ff
ffmpeg    ffplay    ffprobe   ffserver  

masi@masi:~$ require 'ffaker'
bash: require: command not found

masi@masi:~$ sudo ffaker
sudo: ffaker: command not found
```

OS: Debian 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the [Interactive Ruby Shell](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/irb.html) , then run the command:

```
irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'ffaker'
=> true
exit
```

There is an example [from the git repository](https://github.com/ffaker/ffaker/blob/master/REFERENCE.md) :

```
irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'ffaker'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> FFaker::Name.name
=> "Danyelle Langosh"
irb(main):003:0> FFaker::Internet.email
=> "kristle.kiehn@senger.name"
irb(main):004:0>
```

Comment: Do you know any minimal examples about how to generate fake data with the package? I want to test that it really works.

Comment: there is an example [here](http://search.cpan.org/~wsheldahl/Data-Faker-0.09/lib/Data/Faker.pm) , run `cpan Data::Faker` , create your `sample.pl` with the content of the synopsis  then run `perl sample.pl`

Comment: What is the typical configuration for `cpan` installation? Options `(Choose 'local::lib', 'sudo' or 'manual')`. Sudo ok?